# How does a TLS client know the CA certificate?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

Assuming the server doesn't send the root CA certificate along with it's certificate and all the intermediates, how does the client know the root CA certificate in order to validate the server's certificate? Is it by the details of the issuer in the server's certificate? That sounds pretty weird, since who guarantees uniqueness of this?

Comment: The PKI community guarantees uniqueness. Root certificates are added to various root stores through a laborious process that wouldn't accept a new root certificate that has the exact same subject name as an already existing root certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming the server doesn't send the root CA certificate ...

First, a client should never ever trust a root certificate send by the server during the TLS handshake. The root certificate is used to derive the trust into the server certificate and for this the root certificate must be already trusted. Blindly trusting a root certificate send by a server is like trusting somebody just because they claim themselves that they are trustworthy.

> ... how does the client know the root CA certificate in order to validate the server's certificate? Is it by the details of the issuer in the server's certificate?

Yes, it is by the details of the issuer which includes also the authority key identifier. It might be possible that several CA in the  trust store match this condition. In this case all will be tried if any of these can be used to verify the issuer signature of the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

A list of all trusted CAs and their root certificates are stored on the client in the root certificate store. The server's certificate indicates which CA it has been signed by, and the client verifies that using the CAs certificate from the root store.